# Powershell function to import csv file to SQL Server database table

Tags: sql-server, powershell, csv, import

I have created a PowerShell function that bulk copies data from a `.csv` file (first row is the header), and inserts the data in to a SQL Server database table.

See my code:

```
function BulkCsvImport($sqlserver, $database, $table, $csvfile, $csvdelimiter, $firstrowcolumnnames) {
    Write-Host "Bulk Import Started." 
    $elapsed = [System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::StartNew()  
    [void][Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Data") 
    [void][Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Data.SqlClient") 

    # 50k worked fastest and kept memory usage to a minimum 
    $batchsize = 50000 

    # Build the sqlbulkcopy connection, and set the timeout to infinite 
    $connectionstring = "Data Source=$sqlserver;Integrated Security=true;Initial Catalog=$database;" 

    # Wipe the bulk insert table first
    Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "TRUNCATE TABLE $table" -ServerInstance $sqlserver -Database $database

    $bulkcopy = New-Object Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy($connectionstring, [System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopyOptions]::TableLock) 
    $bulkcopy.DestinationTableName = $table 
    $bulkcopy.bulkcopyTimeout = 0 
    $bulkcopy.batchsize = $batchsize 

    # Create the datatable, and autogenerate the columns. 
    $datatable = New-Object System.Data.DataTable 

    # Open the text file from disk 
    $reader = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader($csvfile) 
    $columns = (Get-Content $csvfile -First 1).Split($csvdelimiter) 

    if ($firstrowcolumnnames -eq $true) { $null = $reader.readLine() } 

    foreach ($column in $columns) {  
        $null = $datatable.Columns.Add() 
    } 

    # Read in the data, line by line 
    while (($line = $reader.ReadLine()) -ne $null)  { 
        $null = $datatable.Rows.Add($line.Split($csvdelimiter)) 

        $i++; 
        if (($i % $batchsize) -eq 0) {  
            $bulkcopy.WriteToServer($datatable)  
            Write-Host "$i rows have been inserted in $($elapsed.Elapsed.ToString())." 
            $datatable.Clear()  
        }  
    }  

    # Add in all the remaining rows since the last clear 
    if($datatable.Rows.Count -gt 0) { 
        $bulkcopy.WriteToServer($datatable) 
        $datatable.Clear() 
    } 

    # Clean Up 
    $reader.Close(); 
    $reader.Dispose() 

    $bulkcopy.Close(); 
    $bulkcopy.Dispose() 

    $datatable.Dispose() 

    Write-Host "Bulk Import Completed. $i rows have been inserted into the database." 
    # Write-Host "Total Elapsed Time: $($elapsed.Elapsed.ToString())" 
    # Sometimes the Garbage Collector takes too long to clear the huge datatable. 
    $i = 0
    [System.GC]::Collect()
}
```

I am looking to modify the above though so that the column names in the `.csv` file match up with the column names in the SQL Server database table. They should be identical. At the moment the data is being imported in to the incorrect database columns.

Could I get some assistance as what I need to do to modify the above function to achieve this?

Comment: So much code for what could be easily done using bulk insert. https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/skipping-columns-other-tricks-using-bcp-format-files-sql-spackle-1

Comment: or just import flat file in ssms.  however, the problem is likely that the ordinals of the table columns do not match those in the csv file.  Also you're not specifying a format file to bulk insert, so you're asking for trouble.

Comment: @user1443098 SSMS/SSIS may not be always the option. What is author want to automate it using PS?

Comment: Forgot to install the SqlServer module via `Install-Module SqlServer -Scope CurrentUser` and was getting "The term 'Invoke-Sqlcmd' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet" when trying to use `Invoke-Sqlcmd`.

Answer (score 3):

I would use existing open source solution:

> [Import-DbaCsv - dbatools.io](https://docs.dbatools.io/#Import-DbaCsv)
>
> [Import-DbaCsv.ps1](https://github.com/sqlcollaborative/dbatools/blob/development/functions/Import-DbaCsv.ps1)
>
> Efficiently imports very large (and small) CSV files into SQL Server.
>
> Import-DbaCsv takes advantage of .NET's super fast SqlBulkCopy class to import CSV files into SQL Server.
>
> ---
>
> Parameters:
>
> **-ColumnMap**
>
> By default, the bulk copy tries to automap columns. When it doesn't
>   work as desired, this parameter will help.

```
PS C:\> $columns = @{
>> Text = 'FirstName'
>> Number = 'PhoneNumber'
>> }
PS C:\> Import-DbaCsv -Path c:\temp\supersmall.csv 
        -SqlInstance sql2016 -Database tempdb -ColumnMap $columns 
        -BatchSize 50000 -Table table_name -Truncate
```

> The CSV column 'Text' is inserted into SQL column 'FirstName' and CSV column Number is inserted into the SQL Column 'PhoneNumber'. All other columns are ignored and therefore null or default values.